# How can I run scrapy background in ubuntu?

Tags: scrapy

I developed spider by scrapy, and run it by command

```
scrapy crawl myspider
```

Now I try to run it background by command:

```
nohup scrapy crawl myspider &
```

but after I close ssh session, the scrapy stop, why?

Answer (score -1):

My guess is this has nothing to do with Scrapy.

Does this suggested solution work?
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/658535/what-is-the-real-reason-why-nohup-a-out-dies-when-ssh-session-times-out